# The process of uploading multiple files from a blob to an SFTP server is encountering failures and taking longer time to complete the upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, azure-functions

The process of uploading multiple files from a blob storage to an SFTP server is encountering a recurring issue characterized by socket timeout exceptions.
Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException:
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at Renci.SshNet.Session.WaitOnHandle (Renci.SshNet, Version=2024.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1cee9f8bde3db106)

The occurrence stems from connection timeouts, despite the SFTP client closing the connection after each upload attempt.

A proposed solution entails:

```
1. Retrieving multiple files from a blob using a prefix.
2. Iterating through each file, downloading it into a memory stream.
3. Establishing an SFTP connection and uploading the file.
```

```
     public async Task<bool> DownloadListOfFiles(ILogger log, string prefix, int? segmentSize)
     {
         bool isSuccess = true;
         try
         {
             // Call the listing operation and return pages of the specified size.
             var resultSegment = containerClient.GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync(prefix: prefix, delimiter: "/")
                 .AsPages(default, segmentSize);
    
             // Enumerate the blobs returned for each page.
             await foreach (Page<BlobHierarchyItem> blobPage in resultSegment)
             {
                 // A hierarchical listing may return both virtual directories and blobs.
                 foreach (BlobHierarchyItem blobhierarchyItem in blobPage.Values)
                 //Parallel.ForEach(blobPage.Values, blobhierarchyItem =>
                 {
                     if (blobhierarchyItem.IsPrefix)
                     {
                         // Call recursively with the prefix to traverse the virtual directory.
                         await DownloadListOfFiles(log, blobhierarchyItem.Prefix, null);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         // Write out the name of the blob.
                         var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobhierarchyItem.Blob.Name);
                         string FileName = blobhierarchyItem.Blob.Name;
            var remoteFilePath = $"SFTPPath/ {FileName}";
                                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                                                            await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(stream);
                                        stream.Position = 0;
                                        await PostToSFTP(stream.ToArray(), log, remoteFilePath );
                                                                    }
                     }
                 };
             }
         }
         catch (RequestFailedException e)
         {
             isSuccess = false;
         }
         return isSuccess;
     }
    
    private async Task PostToSFTP(byte[] fileBytes, ILogger log, string remoteFilePath)
    {
            bool isSuccess = true;
            // Create an SFTP client object using the host, port, username, and password
            using (SftpClient sftpclient = new SftpClient(SFTPHost, SFTPPort, SFTPUserName, SFTPPassword))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Connect to the server
                    sftpclient.Connect();
                    sftpclient.KeepAliveInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
                    sftpclient.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
    
                    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
                    {
                        // Upload the file to the remote path
                        sftpclient.UploadFile(stream, remoteFilePath, true);
                    }
                        sftpclient.Disconnect();
                }
                catch (SshException ex)
                {
                    sftpclient.Disconnect();
                    isSuccess = false;
                        if (ex.InnerException != null && ex.InnerException.Message.Contains("Socket read operation has timed out"))
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Close the stream and the connection
                    sftpclient.Disconnect();
                    isSuccess = false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Close the stream and the connection
                    sftpclient.Disconnect();
                    sftpclient.Dispose();
                }
            }
    }
```

The process of uploading 60 small files from a blob storage to an SFTP server is taking significantly longer than anticipated, with an average upload time of around 5 minutes. Additionally, the operation is being interrupted by multiple socket timeout exceptions, further impeding the efficiency and reliability of the process.

Comment: Way back when I was looking for an async SFTP lib, I didn't find one. Can you run any software on the SFTP end to just pull the files direct rather than being a pass-through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions: After experimenting with various solutions, most of which resulted in timeout exceptions, I discovered one approach that not only succeeded but also optimized the overall execution time. The key difference in this successful method compared to others lies in bypassing the step of downloading the file into a stream from the blob. Instead, I directly uploaded the file to the SFTP server. This adjustment not only resolved the timeout issues but also streamlined the execution process, resulting in improved efficiency.

```
    public async Task<bool> DownloadListOfFiles(ILogger log, string prefix, int? segmentSize)
{
    bool isSuccess = true;
    try
    {
        // Call the listing operation and return pages of the specified size.
        var resultSegment = containerClient.GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync(prefix: prefix, delimiter: "/")
            .AsPages(default, segmentSize);
        // Enumerate the blobs returned for each page.
        await foreach (Page<BlobHierarchyItem> blobPage in resultSegment)
        {
            // A hierarchical listing may return both virtual directories and blobs.
            foreach (BlobHierarchyItem blobhierarchyItem in blobPage.Values)
            //Parallel.ForEach(blobPage.Values, blobhierarchyItem =>
            {
                if (blobhierarchyItem.IsPrefix)
                {
                    // Call recursively with the prefix to traverse the virtual directory.
                    await DownloadListOfFiles(log, blobhierarchyItem.Prefix, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Write out the name of the blob.
                    var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobhierarchyItem.Blob.Name);
                    string FileName = blobhierarchyItem.Blob.Name;
                    var remoteFilePath = $"{SFTPPath}/{FileName}";

                    //sftp client is created in constructor 
                    sftpclient.Connect();

                    using (var sftpWriteStream = sftpclient.Create(remoteFilePath))
                    {
                        blobClient.DownloadTo(sftpWriteStream);
                    }
                    sftpclient.Disconnect();
                }
            };
        }
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException e)
    {
        isSuccess = false;
    }
    return isSuccess;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not create and connect a new instance of SftpClient for each file. Create and connect once at the beginning of the process, then reuse the sftpClient instance to do the upload. It will be much quicker.

Comment: I did that too as well means created SFTP client on the class constructor, but same socket exception was troughing. Thank you for your suggestion